# PostgreSQL using variables in FOR Loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE arapply
(
  arapply_id serial NOT NULL,
  arapply_postdate date,
  arapply_source_docnumber text,
  arapply_target_docnumber text,
  arapply_target_paid numeric
);

CREATE TABLE aropenbal
(
  ar_id integer,
  doc_number text,
  doc_type text,
  doc_date date,
  base_amount numeric,
  paid_amount numeric,
  open_balance numeric
);
```

For each entry in `aropenbal`, I want to SUM `arapply.arapply_target_paid` values where `arapply.arapply_source_docnumber = aropenbal.doc_number` (if `aropenbal.doctype` is C or R) or `arapply.arapply_target_docnumber = aropenbal.doc_number` (if `aropenbal.doctype` is not C or R) AND also `arapply_postdate <= aropenbal.doc_date`. The result should be stored to `aropenbal.paid_amount`.

I then wish to update `aropenbal.open_balance` with `aropenbal.base_amount + aropenbal.paid_amount`.

The function should return the total (SUM) of `aropenbal.open_balance`.

I'm having problems with the code below. The SELECT statements inside the FOR loop don't work, unless I manually assign a value say '362' in place of r.docnumber. Otherwise, the result is zero.

Seems to be a formatting problem.

Any insights?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testit() RETURNS NUMERIC AS 
$BODY$

DECLARE
r RECORD;

BEGIN
FOR r IN 
    SELECT * FROM aropenbal ORDER BY doc_date
LOOP

UPDATE aropenbal SET paid_amount = (
    CASE WHEN (doc_type IN ('C', 'R')) THEN
        (SELECT COALESCE (SUM (arapply_target_paid)* -1, 0)
        FROM arapply
        WHERE arapply_source_docnumber = r.doc_number
        AND arapply_postdate <= r.doc_date)
    ELSE
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM (arapply_target_paid),0)
        FROM arapply
        WHERE arapply_target_docnumber = r.doc_number
        AND arapply_postdate <= r.doc_date)
    END) WHERE ar_id = r.ar_id;

UPDATE aropenbal SET open_balance = (base_amount - paid_amount) 
WHERE ar_id = r.ar_id;

END LOOP;

RETURN (SELECT SUM(open_balance) FROM aropenbal);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just added `where` clauses to both `update` statements though that didn't change the result. What other alternative is there to the loop?

Comment: what are the datatypes of arapply_source_docnumber and r.doc_number? if any of them is string type, try to trim both values and if comparison condition works

Comment: Both fields are text. I have tried trimming but it doesn't help. How do I make the comparison? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? Add some sample data and the expected outcome of the loop. It looks like you are trying to update a running sum on `aropenbal`. You might not need to update this at all and simply compute this in a view using window functions. And please add the definitions (`create table`) for both tables.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name please see the explanation I've just added. Hope that helps you understand the objective.